# Access hash key value in array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, hash

I'm trying to obtain the `:visits` value. I'm using this code to access the value

```
puts "#{my_hash[0]['metrics'][0][:visits]}"
```

and getting this error:

```
undefined method `[]'
```

**Edited:** Here is the full output of `puts my_hash`

```
{"xml"=>"<entry><id>ID_DATA</id><updated>2013-04-01T18:10:36.599Z</updated><title type=\"text\">ga:month=01 | ga:year=2013</title><link rel=\"alternate\" type=\"text/html\" href=\"http://www.google.com/analytics\" /><dxp:dimension name=\"ga:month\" value=\"01\" /><dxp:dimension name=\"ga:year\" value=\"2013\" /><dxp:metric name=\"ga:visits\" type=\"integer\" value=\"26248\" /><dxp:metric name=\"ga:bounces\" type=\"integer\" value=\"17174\" /></entry>", "id"=>"https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data?ids=ga:45872215&amp;ga:month=01&amp;ga:year=2013&amp;start-date=2013-01-01&amp;end-date=2013-03-28", "updated"=>Mon, 01 Apr 2013 18:10:36 +0000, "title"=>"ga:month=01 | ga:year=2013", "dimensions"=>[{:month=>"01"}, {:year=>"2013"}], "metrics"=>[{:visits=>26248.0}, {:bounces=>17174.0}]}
{"xml"=>"<entry><id>ID_DATA</id><updated>2013-04-01T18:10:36.599Z</updated><title type=\"text\">ga:month=02 | ga:year=2013</title><link rel=\"alternate\" type=\"text/html\" href=\"http://www.google.com/analytics\" /><dxp:dimension name=\"ga:month\" value=\"02\" /><dxp:dimension name=\"ga:year\" value=\"2013\" /><dxp:metric name=\"ga:visits\" type=\"integer\" value=\"24808\" /><dxp:metric name=\"ga:bounces\" type=\"integer\" value=\"16716\" /></entry>", "id"=>"https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data?ids=ga:45872215&amp;ga:month=02&amp;ga:year=2013&amp;start-date=2013-01-01&amp;end-date=2013-03-28", "updated"=>Mon, 01 Apr 2013 18:10:36 +0000, "title"=>"ga:month=02 | ga:year=2013", "dimensions"=>[{:month=>"02"}, {:year=>"2013"}], "metrics"=>[{:visits=>24808.0}, {:bounces=>16716.0}]}
{"xml"=>"<entry><id>ID_DATA</id><updated>2013-04-01T18:10:36.599Z</updated><title type=\"text\">ga:month=03 | ga:year=2013</title><link rel=\"alternate\" type=\"text/html\" href=\"http://www.google.com/analytics\" /><dxp:dimension name=\"ga:month\" value=\"03\" /><dxp:dimension name=\"ga:year\" value=\"2013\" /><dxp:metric name=\"ga:visits\" type=\"integer\" value=\"23556\" /><dxp:metric name=\"ga:bounces\" type=\"integer\" value=\"16261\" /></entry>", "id"=>"https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data?ids=ga:45872215&amp;ga:month=03&amp;ga:year=2013&amp;start-date=2013-01-01&amp;end-date=2013-03-28", "updated"=>Mon, 01 Apr 2013 18:10:36 +0000, "title"=>"ga:month=03 | ga:year=2013", "dimensions"=>[{:month=>"03"}, {:year=>"2013"}], "metrics"=>[{:visits=>23556.0}, {:bounces=>16261.0}]}
```

I'm using the Gattica `to_hash` method. https://github.com/chrisle/gattica

```
my_hash = data.to_h['points']
```

Comment: Where is `my_hash` getting set?

Comment: What is output when you `puts my_hash` rather than `puts "#{my_hash[0]['metrics'][0][:visits]}"` ? I want to see the full structure of it

Comment: The above data is the output for `puts my_hash`.

Comment: The above data is not valid output no matter how you slice it.

Comment: I included the full output. I was trying to make it easier to read before.

Comment: Let's take this one single step at a time. To carefully find the single place where this is failing. What is the output of `puts my_hash['metrics']` ? Then `puts my_hash['metrics'][0]` ? Then `puts my_hash['metrics'][0][:visits]` ?

Comment: `puts my_hash['metrics']` produces error: `can't convert String into Integer`

Comment: I hate to keep asking dumb questions for you to do, but just out of curiosity, what is the output of `my_hash.class` and `my_hash.keys` ? I want to be thorough in this investigation.

Comment: Class is array. For keys I get `undefined method `keys'`

Comment: Well then. `my_hash` isn't a hash. What is `my_hash.first`, `my_hash.first.class`, and `my_hash.first.keys` ? Taking these little steps one by one will help find where it is going wrong.

Comment: `my_hash.first.class` is a `Gattica::DataPoint`. Thanks for the help. I guess I need to figure out what that is.

Comment: http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2012/190/d/e/adventure_time__mathematical__by_kingsizedkoala-d56mrlh.jpg

Comment: `DataPoint` has `attr_reader :id, :updated, :title, :dimensions, :metrics, :xml`, which means you can: `puts my_hash.first.metrics[:visits]`

Comment: Ok I'm getting close! When I do `puts my_hash.first.metrics` it outputs `{:visits=>26248.0}
{:bounces=>17174.0}` but `puts my_hash.first.metrics[:visits]` gives me error `can't convert Symbol into Integer`

Comment: The documentation gives this **ridiculous** incantation: `puts my_hash.first.metrics.detect { |metric| metric.key == :visits }.value`

Comment: I'm posting that as an answer because otherwise this wasn't work the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation gives this ridiculous incantation:

```
puts my_hash.first.metrics.detect { |metric| metric.key == :visits }.value
```

Comment: You can probably tell I'm a complete newb with RoR. I'm not sure which is worse, my competence or this library. I may just try to find a simple REST client to use instead

Comment: Well that's coming straight from the documentation. I think it's the library. They're doing some pretty tricky things here that's not exactly standard. If you really care to continue down this path, open an issue on their github: https://github.com/chrisle/gattica/issues

Comment: I appreciate your help. According to the docs, this is the correct answer.